# How to echo this plug in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

How do I echo a Wordpress plug in short code that I will be putting in the Custom Meta field in the post I have called Treatment 1?

Short code is

```
[table id=6 /]
```

My php which I cant work is

```
<?php 
$post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Treatment Right 1", true);
if (!empty($post_meta)) {
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode($post_meta;); ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please help

Comment: Check whether you got any data in $post_meta and then check for ; mentioned by @Kev Price.

Comment: [table id=6 /] is in the $post_meta but echoing out as that on the page

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode($post_meta); ?>
```

You have a semi colon inside your shortcode function for a start.

not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve.

Does the custom meta field just contain the name of the shortcode or the full string?
i.e. does it include the square brackets [shortcode] rather than just returning 'shortcode'

you could try:

echo do_shortcode('['.$post_meta.']');

have you written the shortcode function of 'table' yourself?

Comment: It is the Table Reload plug in for Wordpress. That short code is meant for the visual editor to echo the table in the post. I am trying to echo that out into the template below the textbox editor via the cusom meta I have names Treatments 1, Treatments 2, Treatments 3 etc..

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked!! echo do_shortcode('['.$post_meta.']');